# Unable to access UI due to /var/www/htdocs/ is forbidden issue on mac+docker

Tags: macos, docker

I downloaded Docker on mac and using "Docker Desktop" to work with docker.

I have small react app (created via create-react-app) in which at root I have created etc dir as below which contain DockerFile under docker dir and `nginx.conf`

[image]

At root I use below command to build image:

```
    docker build . -f etc/docker/Dockerfile -t myui:rc0
```

and then run the container as below:

```
    docker container run -it -p 8081:8081 myui:rc0
```

Error Logs

```
2020/02/11 05:38:08 [error] 6#6: *6 directory index of "/var/www/htdocs/" is forbidden, client: 172.17.0.1, server: localhost, request: "HEAD / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8081"
172.17.0.1 - - [11/Feb/2020:05:38:08 +0000] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 403 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) DockerDesktop/2.1.1 Chrome/78.0.3904.94 Electron/7.1.0 Safari/537.36"
```

Here is the content of my Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:1.15

ARG IMAGE_EXPIRY_TIME=60d

COPY etc/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY myui /var/www/htdocs/myui

RUN touch /var/run/nginx.pid && \
  chown -R www-data:www-data /var/run/nginx.pid && \
  chown -R www-data:www-data /var/cache/nginx

USER www-data

VOLUME /var/www

EXPOSE 8081
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

and here is `nginx.conf` content:

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  2;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       8081;
        server_name  localhost;

        root  /var/www/htdocs/;

        location /myui {
            alias /var/www/htdocs/;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }
    include servers/*;
}
```

Can anyone please help me with this issue.
Thanks

Comment: I do not see `myui` in the root of Dockerfile, So i do think it coping `myui`, one way is to verify `docker container run --name test -it -p 8081:8081 myui:rc0 ` then `docker exec -it test ash -c "cd /var/www/htdocs/; ls` see the files if exist.

Comment: It looks like you could have a directory permissions issue

Comment: Thanks for the response. I do copy myui to docker via
COPY myui /var/www/htdocs/myui

Comment: i guess yes I am not able to access any file

docker exec -it myui1 index.html -c "cd /var/www/htdocs/myui/"
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "exec: \"index.html\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown

But when I see it via "Docker Desktop" terminal I see all the file in directory  /var/www/htdocs/myui/

Comment: I tried docker exec -it myui1 ls /var/www/htdocs/myui and it works

Comment: Anyone, please help here